# JAVA - my next button is not working right but it returns the first row ID only

Tags: java, derby

im new in java programming and im confused of what i am doing although some are self explanatory and i can understand. but with my code i don't know what really went wrong. i can insert data from database but when i click next with my current code it returns only the ID field not populating the other textboxes and it also returns the 1st row.

here is my code for next button

```
    private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mim";
        String username = "is2560";
        String password = "is2560";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String query = "SELECT * from students";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);           
        if (rs.next()){
            int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
            String id = Integer.toString(ID);
            String Fname = rs.getString("FNAME");
            String Mname = rs.getString("MNAME");
            String Lname = rs.getString("LNAME");
            String Stdno = rs.getString("STUDENTNO");
            String Course = rs.getString("COURSE");

            txtCourse.setText(Course);
            txtFName.setText(Fname);
            txtMname.setText(Mname);
            txtLname.setText(Lname);
            txtStdnt.setText(Stdno);
            txtID.setText(id);
        }
        else {
            rs.previous();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "End of File");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: you execute always the select again. from your source code it is correct that only the first row is displayed. I think you need an index as a class member and a limit in your sql.

Comment: sorry what is index as a class member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1 Create a class `Student`:

```
public class Student {

  private int mId;
  private String mFirstname;
  private String mLastName;
  private String mMName;
  private String mInfo;
  private String mCourse;
  public int getId() {
    return mId;
  }
  public void setId(int pId) {
    this.mId = pId;
  }
  public String getFirstname() {
    return mFirstname;
  }
  public void setFirstname(String pFirstname) {
    this.mFirstname = pFirstname;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return mLastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String pLastName) {
    this.mLastName = pLastName;
  }
  public String getMName() {
    return mMName;
  }
  public void setMName(String pMName) {
    this.mMName = pMName;
  }
  public String getInfo() {
    return mInfo;
  }
  public void setInfo(String pInfo) {
    this.mInfo = pInfo;
  }
  public String getCourse() {
    return mCourse;
  }
  public void setCourse(String pCourse) {
    this.mCourse = pCourse;
  }
}
```

step 2 define 2 class members in you class:

```
private List<Student> mAllStudent = new ArrayList<>;
private int mClickIndex = 0;
```

step 3 Load all Students from derby:

```
private void loadAllStudent(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mim";
        String username = "is2560";
        String password = "is2560";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String query = "SELECT * from students";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);           
        while (rs.next()){
            Student lStudent = new Student();
      lStudent.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
      lStudent.setFirstname(rs.getString("FNAME"));
      lStudent.setLastName(rs.getString("LNAME"));
      lStudent.setMName(rs.getString("MNAME"));
      lStudent.setInfo(rs.getString("STUDENTNO"));
      lStudent.setCourse(rs.getString("COURSE"));
      mAllStudent.add(lStudent);


        }
        else {
            rs.previous();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "End of File");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

step 4 implement the nextButton logic:

```
private void showNext(){
   if (mClickIndex == mAllStudent.size()){
      mClickIndex = 0; // start at beginning after end is reached.
   }
   Student lStudent = mAllStudent.get(mClickIndex);
   mClickIndex++;
   if (null != lStudent){
        txtCourse.setText(lStudent.getCourse());
        txtFName.setText(lStudent.getFirstname());
        txtMname.setText(lStudent.getMName());
        txtLname.setText(lStudent.getLastname());
        txtStdnt.setText(lStudent.getInfo());
        txtID.setText(lStudent.getId());
   }
}
```

before you call showNext you have to load all students for example in the constructor of you class or in the init method if you have one.

Comment: is this a function to call on button? i use derby as database

Comment: i already did and it works great! thank you! the rest of the function will be up to me now :)

Answer (score 0):

Brother Instead of 
     `if (rs.next()){` this line you have to use

while(rs.next()){

try and tel me

Comment: i tried and the textboxes were populated! but it returned the last row.

Comment: @Sathees how to share it?

Comment: @Kim caboteja think about the while! it iterates over all entries in your table. the while condition ends with the last element.

Comment: @StefanBeike yes i figured it out now, what i need is the next function button

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: @StefanBeike sorry about last comment i mean the next button. i use derby or the embeded database